# HTML / JS library to function as Android screen keyboard

Tags: java, jquery, html

I need to have keyboard panel (like Android mobile devices have) which will slide when focus is on some input. Also it should have close button to close itself. I assume jQuery is capable of helping with that but I think out there should be the solution. What is the best choice to complete the task?

Example of overlay keyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/onscreenkeyboard/) is something what you need, but I am not shure if it already supports sliding, but you can add this future on your own.

**UPDATE**

[Another one](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html)?